# On the alternative statements of the famous Sperner's Lemma.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, big-list

Sperner's Lemma can be stated as follows.

> **Lemma of Sperner.** Let $\Omega$ a finite set with $n$ elements ( $|\Omega|=n$). If a family $\{ A_i \}_{1\leq i \leq N}\subset \Omega$  satisfies the Sperner condition, *i.e.* $A_i\nsubseteq A_j$ and $A_j\nsubseteq A_i$ for all $i \neq j$, then 
>   $$
> N \leq \frac{n!}{ \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor ! \left(n-\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor\right) !}
> $$

Here, $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor$ is the integer part of $ \frac{n}{2}$.

> **Question.**  What other statements of Sperner's Lemma exist?

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_lemma), for example, there is a different statement of Sperner's Lemma. I ask that your statement of Sperner's Lemma to be accompanied by a proof that the statement of Sperner's Lemma in this question  and the statement of Sperner's Lemma in your answer are equivalent  or at least an indication of a book, article or link that contains the proof of such equivalence.

Comment: You are mixing up two different Sperner theorems. The one that you call "Lemma of Sperner" is also called [Sperner's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem). The other one that you linked to on Wikipedia, about colorings of triangulations of a simplex, is really not related. It is not a different statement of the same lemma. It is a different and unrelated theorem (only related because discovered by the same person).